# jquery как обратиться ко всем элементам страницы или ко все элементам формы

Tags: jquery

jquery как обратиться ко всем элементам страницы или ко все элементам формы

Comment: * - все элементы страницы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский речь таки про контролы формы, судя по всему.

Comment: @teran ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  возможно

Answer (score 1):

селекторы объединяются через запятую

```
$("#myform").find("input, select, textarea").doSomething()
```

Comment: Ещё есть `datalist`. Но это, конечно, для тех, кто очень в теме))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так он не визуальный и значения не содержит.

Comment: Ааа. Это для инпута. Ясно)